# Prove or disprove $a = b^c \bmod d$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

How do I prove or disprove that $a = b^c \bmod d$?
For example, I have $9 = 10^{1001}\bmod 11$.

Comment: $\color\red{10^2}\equiv\color\red{1}\pmod{11}\implies10^{1001}\equiv10^{2\cdot500+1}\equiv(\color\red{10^2})^{500}\cdot10\equiv\color\red{1}^{500}\cdot10\equiv10\pmod{11}$

Answer (score 2):

For integer $n\ge0,$

$$10\equiv-1\pmod{11}\implies10^{2n+1}\equiv(-1)^{2n+1}\equiv-1\pmod{11}$$

But $$9\not\equiv-1\pmod{11}$$

Comment: Why does 10 ≡ −1(mod11) means that 10^2n+1 ≡ −1(mod11) as well?

Comment: @Gil, As $$a\equiv b\pmod m, a^r\equiv b^r$$

Comment: Got it, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

$10\equiv -1(mod 11) \Rightarrow 10^{1001}\equiv(-1)^{1001}(mod11)\Rightarrow 10^{1001}\equiv-1(mod11)$

therefor the statement $9\equiv10^{1001}(mod11)$ is false.